# How to extract a sum data from a text file on Python

Tags: python, text-files, data-analysis

I have a text file txt that has 6 columns:
1.sex (M /F)     2.age   3.height    4.weight    5.-/+   6.zip code

I need to find from this text how many Males have - sign. ( for example: from the txt 30 M(Males) are - )

So I need only the number at the end.

Logically I need to work with Column1 and column 5 but I am struggling to get only one (sum) number at the end.

This is the content of the text:

```
M 87  66 133 - 33634
M 17  77 119 - 33625
M 63  57 230 - 33603
F 55  50 249 - 33646
M 45  51 204 - 33675
M 58  49 145 - 33629
F 84  70 215 - 33606
M 50  69 184 - 33647
M 83  60 178 - 33611
M 42  66 262 - 33682
M 33  75 176 + 33634
M 27  48 132 - 33607
```

I am getting the result now..., but I want both M and positive. How can I add that to occurrences??

```
f=open('corona.txt','r')
data=f.read()
occurrences=data.count('M')
print('Number of Males that have been tested positive:',occurrences)
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show your existing code and what doesn't work as expected

Comment: share the code and few lines of the txt file

Comment: I tried it using csv and enumerate but I need to do it using simple syntax.

Comment: please share you code to see what you have tried ...

Comment: please copy your code and paste it here, it is easer for us to help u

Comment: It is the custom on SO to post your code in a code block in your post.  This enable other users to copy & paste it to their environments, and make suggestions.

Comment: So this is my starting code, I want to use this simple syntax. Is it possible now from my text file to read how much M(male) have (-) , a total number at the end.

Comment: Hello there! As a minimum I think you should look at an intro on how to use python, it seems like you don't quite have the hang of the basics with reading files, just yet. In case you haven't already, as a new user, take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) .

Comment: @JakobGuldbergAaes Well if I had experience I wouldn't be here, don't you think???!! I am asking for some help as novice I am.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do any significant amount of work with text and columnar data, I would suggest getting started on learning `pandas`

For this task, if your csv is one record per line and is space-delimited:

```
import pandas as pd
d = pd.read_csv('data.txt', 
        names=['Sex', 'Age', 'Height', 'Weight', 'Sign', 'ZIP'], 
        sep=' ', index_col=False)

d[(d.Sex=='M') & (d.Sign=='-')].shape[0] # or
len(d[(d.Sex=='M') & (d.Sign=='-')]) # same result, in this case = 9
```

`Pandas` is a very extensive package.  What this code does is build a `DataFrame` from your csv data, giving each column a name.  Then selects from this, each row where both of your conditions `Sex == 'M'` and `Sign == '-'`, and reports the number of records thus found.

I recommend starting [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/10min.html)

Comment: Thank you very much! But I should not used other libraries, i should get the result using simple syntax basic ones: like open() read and using a loop maybe.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood "Simple Syntax" as "Consise Syntax", rather than "without using add on packages".  Can you update your OP with code you have already tried using open built-ins, and the results you got?

Comment: Is there any possible way to get the same result but defining it in this way:
file=open('mf.txt','r') 
for line in file: 
print(line) 
file.close()

Answer (score 1):

You can split the lines like this:

```
occurrences = 0
with open('corona.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        cells = line.split()
        if cells[0] == "M" and cells[4] == "-":
            occurrences += 1
print("Occurrences of M-:", occurrences)
```

But it is better to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module or `pandas` for this type of work.

Comment: Yes this is what I was looking for. Thanks a lot! Appreciate it :)